# RaspberryPi with Python: How to stop Servo and Start again

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, servo

When i stop the servo after an action and want to start it again the servo is moving strange. The servo seems to move out of range.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(17, 50)
p.start(2.5)
time.sleep(3)
p.ChangDutyCycle(12.5)
time.sleep(3)
p.ChangDutyCycle(2.5)
time.sleep(3)
p.stop()
p.start(2.5)
# this is not working
p.ChangDutyCycle(12.5)
p.stop()
```

The servo should normally start again and make the movement. It think it maybe sets the start position wrong and wants to move in the other direction.

Comment: Just a few thoughts - I don't have practical experience with servos: your duty cycles seem a bit off - normally servos get pulses between 1 and 2 ms, which corresponds to 5-10% duty cycle at 50 Hz. Your 2.5-12.5% is 0.5-2.5 ms, which may work with your servo but looks a bit strange. The other thing is that you're stopping, starting and switching the duty cycle directly in sequence, it might be better to have a small delay or start with the desired value. Or maybe don't stop and start at all, servos are designed to get a continuous signal.

Comment: What servo type do you use? The normal servo timing is 1 ms for 0°, 1.5 ms for 90° and 2 ms for 180°, so your timings aren´t correct. For a 1 ms pulse you need a duty cycle of 5%.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I wrote this code only to display the problem, in my actual code I wait ca.3 seconds

Comment: So at which point does it behave strangely? When you stop? When you start again? When you change duty cycle after starting?

Comment: I tried changing the duty cycle but the error still occurs. Can it be that I cannot switch the servo multiple times on and off?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner when it start again. Yes, I can change duty Cycle but the servo doesnt moves. THe servo only vibrates

Comment: There are several articles on PWM start/stop problems, it seems the best approach is to just let the PWM run if you don't have a good reason to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem not very elegant, but I didn't found any better solution. I made an extra file with all the servo moves and executed it with `os.system("path to file")` in the main program. In the separate file I initialized the servo pins and started the servo. At the end I stopped the servo and cleaned only the servo pins to not break the main program with other pins involved. The problem is that you have to set the servos back to the start position at the end of the separate file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can use my library which hides most of the pwm and GPIO board complexity. Sample code:

```
from RaspberryMotors.motors import servos
s1 = servos.servo(11)  #create the servo objects , connected to GPIO board pin #11 
s1.setAngleAndWait(45) # move S1 position of 45 degrees
s1.shutdown()  #will clean up the GPIO board as well
```

You can view download the code or the library via any of the two links:
https://github.com/vikramdayal/RaspberryMotors
or
https://pypi.org/project/RaspberryMotors/#description

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is correct, but, after the stop if you create again the PWM it works. So:

```
p = GPIO.PWM(17, 50)
p.start(2.5)
time.sleep(3)
p.ChangDutyCycle(12.5)
p.stop()

# create it again
p = GPIO.PWM(17, 50)
p.start(12.5)
time.sleep(3)
p.ChangDutyCycle(4)
p.stop()
```